# What are this character's last words in The Dark Knight?

Tags: dc, batman, nolan-batman-trilogy, the-dark-knight

She's obviously cut off before she's blown up. But just wondering if anyone had an idea of what she was going to say. What are Rachel Dawes last words in The Dark Knight?

Comment: Eh... spoilers?

Answer (score 26):

The sentence starts "Somewhere...", but is cut off. We can speculate as to how that sentence is going to end, but ultimately we just don't know.

The following is an screencap of [The Dark Knight's script](https://stephenfollows.com/resource-docs/scripts/dark_knight._The_.pdf):

[image: A page from the script of The Dark Knight; transcript of the relevant part follows]

> DENT (CONT'D)
>   RACHEL!
>
> RACHEL (O.S.)
>   Harvey? Harvey, it's okay...
>
> DENT
>   RACHEL!!!
>
> EXT. 52ND STREET, GOTHAM -- NIGHT
>
> Gordon, axe in hand, RUNS towards the entrance-
>
> INT. WAREHOUSE -- NIGHT
>
> Rachel can hear Dent. The counter runs out.
>
> RACHEL
>   (calm)
>   Somehwere-
>
> AN EXPLOSION. ALL-CONSUMING.

Comment: I'd move that last section up before the transcript image, since it's the most important part of your answer.

Comment: Typo in the most important word: "Somehwere"

Comment: Turns out, she was about to launch into a heart-wrenching rendition of "Somewhere out there", from American Tail.  They decided the mice did it better and cut it out of the film.

Comment: I thought she was going for somewhere over the rainbow...

Comment: _"somewhere I belong"_..

Answer (score 11):

According to [the novelization by Dennis O'Neill](http://4thletter.net/2008/08/the-dark-knight-the-deleted-scenes/) which was likely based on an earlier script:

> “Bruce… Harvey… I love you.”

Of course, that doesn't match with the movie dialogue, where she starts with "Some—" before she's cut off. [Fan speculation](https://en.wikiquote.org/wiki/Last_words_in_Batman_media#The_Dark_Knight_.282008.29) has largely been that she was saying something like "Someone is coming to get me" although a few have suggested she's instead trying to tell him there's a mole in the office, "Someone in our office is working with the mob."

Answer (score 11):

Just rewatched the [scene](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-gGbAA_-IC4), her (actually spoken) last words are

> Harvey, it's okay. Its alright. Listen. [start of unknown word] [BOOOM!].

From both the context of the scene (as she seems to try to calm Harvey down) and the sound of [start of unknown word] (which sounds like "some" to me), my best guess would be something similar to

> Someone will come to save me too.